# Javascript regex email validation

Tags: javascript, php, regex, validation, email

I have used regex to test for the email input. It does give an alert when a wrong email (for eg without an @ or .com) is submitted but when I press ok for the alert, it still posts the email to the email address that is am directed to the page send_msg.php when it should not.. I am quite new to Javascript and PHP so I am still learning.. I know that the *if* clause should follow an *else* but I don't know how to make it post the email if it is true. And can how I make it just display a message below the email input field instead of making it raise an alert?

```
<script>
function checkEmail(inputvalue){    
var pattern=/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;
if(pattern.test!=(inputvalue)){  
         alert("Please enter a valid email address");  
         return false;


}
```

}

```
<form id="contact-form" name= "form1 "action="send_msg.php" method="post">
        <h3>Get in touch</h3>
        <h4>Fill in the form below, and we'll get back to you within 24 hours.</h4>
        <div>
            <label>
                <span>Name: </span>
                <input placeholder="Please enter your name" name="name" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
                <span>Email: </span>
                <input placeholder="Please enter your email address" name="email" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>
                <span >Message: </span>
                <textarea placeholder="Include all the details you can" name="message" tabindex="5" size= "35" maxlength= "255"></textarea>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button name="submit" type="submit" onClick="checkEmail(document.contact-form.email.value)" id="contact-submit">Send Email</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Just add `return false;` at the end of your `if` statement.

Comment: For completeness, [RFC 5322](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.4.1) allows the use off `+` in email addresses e.g `foo+bar@example.com`, your current regex would fail that email.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the regex validation is ok, you can prevent the form to submit, simply by doing this:

```
<form onsubmit="return checkEmail(document.contact-form.email.value);" id="contact-form" name= "form1 "action="send_msg.php" method="post">
...
</form>
```

And remove the `onClick` from the submit button. If the regex function returns true if valid and false if not valid, than the form will submit only when the email input has valid data in it.

Comment: I have tried it but it is still not working.. It still sends the email.. I think the problem lies in the regex validation:  
 `<script>
  function checkEmail(inputvalue){ 
    var pattern=/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;
    if(pattern.test!=(inputvalue)){  
             alert("Your email address is invalid!"); 
            return false;   
  
    }
 
 
 
}
  </script>`

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

seems like your function has syntax error use it this way

```
function checkEmail(inputvalue){    
var pattern=/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;
         return pattern.test(inputvalue); 
}
checkEmail('rte@co') // false
checkEmail('rte@co.com') // true
```

Comment: Also.. you can simplify the regex to `/^([\w.-])+@([\w.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+/`